# Python List Continuation with multiple lambdas applied

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I'm attempting to apply multiple filters and maps to a list and attempted to refactor into something i believe is more readable. In my code, I am reading a file to create a list of terms, then munging it into something I will feed into another script.

Please note my terminology in the title might be wrong, but please feel free to correct.

Originally, I had something that looked like this:

```
random_substring = lambda word: word[:(random.randrange(len(word) - 2) + 1)]

only_longer_words = lambda word: len(word) > 2 

terms = []

#File manipulation that adds words to terms

terms = filter(only_longer_words, terms)
terms = map(random_substring, terms)
terms = filter(only_longer_words, terms)

#Save terms to file
```

After refactoring, I created a ChainList which inherits from list:

```
class ChainList(list):
    def filter(self, function):
        return ChainList(filter(function, self))

    def map(self, function):
        return ChainList(map(function, self))

    def uniquify(self):
        return ChainList(OrderedDict.fromkeys(self))
```

and use it as such:

```
terms = ChainList()

working_list = (
    terms.filter(only_longer_words)
         .map(random_substring)
         .filter(only_longer_words) 
         .uniquify()
)
```

The intent is to make it easy to chain operations on lists. It works, but as a Python beginner, wanted a review.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I think I cleaned it up appropriately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement is "to apply multiple filters and maps to a list".  This suggests that a good solution is one that takes the list as input applies the composition of operations *to that list*.  Nothing in the problem statement suggests (to me) the creation of a new list-like object with new abilities. I would therefore take a different approach to this problem: stepwise construction of a composed function.  (You may also want to look at Colin Winter's `functional` module.)

```
import collections
class Composer(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.flst = []
  def __call__(self, lst):
    result = lst
    for func in self.flst:
      result = func(result)
    return result
  def add_map(self, func):
    self.flst.append( lambda x: map(func, x) )
  def add_filter(self, func):
    self.flst.append( lambda x: filter(func, x) )
  def uniquify(self):
    #assume hashable objects
    uniquifier = lambda x: collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()
    self.flst.append( lambda x: uniquifier( x ) )

#Example
c = Composer()
c.add_map(lambda x: x*x)
c.add_filter(lambda x: x<30)
c.uniquify()

x = range(10) * 2    
print(c(x))
```

Comment: is it just a matter of preference then? In my example, I have the capability to compose on the fly, whereas in your example you compose a discreet set of operations.

Comment: Here is one perspective on this: you introduce a new type of object whose current state is completely opaque because it is a side effect of previous method calls.  In contrast, a `Composer` keeps a full list of the operations it will apply and application of a composer has no side effects.  (You could make this more precisely true by using a Builder pattern to produce your composers.)

Comment: Perhaps there is a difference in style depending on use. In this example, I am using it as a script that i will be constantly tweaking to work with different data sets. If this were part of a more static code base, I can see your point. I appreciate your feedback which was exactly what I was looking for in posting this example. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem with your code was the formatting issues (PEP8 violations), which you already fixed, with the exception of `workingList` which should be `working_list`.

Doc strings would be nice.

Instead of "uniquify", perhaps `unique` or even `uniq` *sounds* better.

In your first lambda you used `word` as the variable, in the second you used `x`. It would be more natural to unify.

This code *doesn't make your ass look fat*, I think.

Comment: Thanks @janos, I updated the code sample with the changes to workingList and made the lambdas consistent. I was looking for comments related to creating a new list and chaining methods together.

Comment: Actually you're not supposed to edit the code in your post at all, as it invalidates the reviews.

Comment: Ah, got it. Sorry about that